# Magento2 Chrome Driver Service error in MTF

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, magentomodule, ftf, mtf

I am new to MTF. I have followed the magento2 tutorial based on the following [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_introduction.html)

But When I am running the command

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I am getting the following error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: nable to
> create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.14.0',
> revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22 693Z' System info:
> host: 'WTW-HP', ip: '192.168.0.31', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
> 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '10.0.2'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown in
> C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\func
> tional\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driv
> er.php:165 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-seleniu
>
> m\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php(71):
> PHPUnit_Extensions_Seleni um2TestCase_Driver->curl('POST',
> Object(PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_URL ), Array)
>
> ## 1 C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-seleniu
>
> m\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\SessionStrategy\Isolated.php(67):
> PHPUnit
> _Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Driver->startSession(Array, Object(PHPUnit_Extensi ons_Selenium2Test in
> C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional\vendor\phpun
> it\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php on
> line 165

My goal is to learn the MTF and integrate the tests into My custom module

Comment: First of all, Windows is not a support env for Magento 2. Still, if you want to run on windows, you need to update to chrome-driver from the binaries available at Google, and setup Selenium Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install chrome drivers for selenium.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring due to the google chrome driver version.

You should install the driver version compatible with your chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

Review your dev/tests/functional/phpunit.xml configuration file

```
<php>
    <const name="SELENIUM_BROWSER" value="chrome"/>
    <const name="SELENIUM_HOST" value="localhost"/>
    <const name="SELENIUM_PORT" value="4444"/>
    <const name="SELENIUM_PATH" value="/path/to/chromedriver"/>
</php>
```

Run WebDriver Manually:

```
/path/to/chromedriver
```

in commandline.